# Access database not updating through the Textboxes in Vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, textbox

I am using Vb.Net to update my access database with some textboxes. This is the code that I have which doesn't give any error when the 'update' button is clicked in the form, but nothing happens either. For some reason the database doesn't get updated. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Dim pro As String
        Dim connstring As String
        Dim command As String
        Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

        pro = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= C:\Users\Hamza\Documents\POS system1.accdb"
        connstring = pro
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim Str = "Update Customers SET  FirstName=?, LastName=?, Address=?, PhoneNo=?, Points=? WHERE CustID=?"
        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", CustIDTextBox)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", First_NameTextBox)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Last_NameTextBox)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", AddressTextBox)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", Phone_noTextBox)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Points", PointsTextBox)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Updated!")
```

Comment: Move the line with the parameter @CustID as the last one added. In OleDb parameters are positional

Comment: Also are those parameter values the names of the textboxes? If yes you have another error because the value of the TextBox is in the Text property

Comment: @Steve Thank you. But what do you mean by the second point? Do I have to convert the textboxes into text first?

Comment: PointsTextBox.Text, CustIDTextBox.Text and so on. You need to pass the value not the textbox itself in the AddWithValue. Also remember that AddWithValue is tricky to use. Numeric values with decimals, DateTime values suffers from the localization problem. Always use Add passing the type expected by the database column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection.

OleDb (used with Access) does not care about the names of parameters. The order that they appear in the sql string must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection. Thus, move the CustID to the end of the parameters being added because it is the last thing in the sql string.

I was very glad to see that you are using parameters. The `Add` method gives you a much better chance of sending the proper datatype to the database. I wasn't sure if the TextBox variables were text boxes that needed the `Text` property or variables you had set. I had to guess at the datatypes. Check your database for the actual types.

Connections and Commands need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks accomplish this for us. It also closes the connection. You didn't close your connection at all.

Don't open the connection until directly before the Execute...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Str = "Update Customers SET  FirstName=?, LastName=?, Address=?, PhoneNo=?, Points=? WHERE CustID=?"
    Dim pro = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= C:\Users\Hamza\Documents\POS system1.accdb"
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(pro),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(Str, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = First_NameTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Last_NameTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AddressTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Phone_noTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Points", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(PointsTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(CustIDTextBox.Text)
        myconnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    MsgBox("Updated!")
End Sub
```